# How can I animate characters' static-geometry eyes?

Tags: textures, animation, geometry, character

Here's a Nintendo example:

[image: Super Mario 3D World]

Specifically, the animation of the pupils seems not to animate the geometry.

How is this done?

Comment: [This](http://www.benjones.us/twilight-princess-eyes-breakdown/) might be relevant to the question

Comment: Excellent! thanks ssb, that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

There can be a texture with the pupils and generous padding around them. On render, geometry just changes UV coords to sample from texture - hence smooth pupils movement on static geometry.